# PHP MYSQL: Data is getting reset to 0's when trying to edit

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to create a php code that will link to MYSQL, so the user can add data, delete and edit. Howerver, I'm currently having an issue so if the user wishes to edit some data, it will reset the last 3 columns to 0's. If I edit a data during the last 3 columns, it will not be eddited and instead be replaced with 0's at the last 3 columns.

```
{
  $eBranch=$_POST['eBranch'];
  $eSales=$_POST['eSales'];
  $eQuantity=$_POST['eQuantity'];
  $eChargeNO=$_Post['eChargeNO'];
  $eCreditNO=$_Post['eCreditNO'];
  $eTotal=$_Post['eTotal'];
  $updated=mysql_query("UPDATE report SET  BranchID='$eBranch', Sales_Assistant_ID='$eSales', Quantity='$eQuantity' , Charge_Accounts='$eChargeNO', Credit_Accounts='$eCreditNO', Total='$eTotal' WHERE id='$id'")or die();

  if($updated)
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  header('Location:index.php');
  }
}
}
```

Please ask me if you need more information! I'm not sure if this is enough

Comment: Have you actually checked that the $_POST values are being passed as you expect?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` would tell you.

Comment: *"Question has been solved - I did not capitalize my _POST"* - From your edit. No need to do that. Accepting the answer was good enough ;-) I had to do a rollback, otherwise people visiting the question may ask "why the answers?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see these `$_Post`?

They're a superglobal and **must** be in uppercase `$_POST`

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

---

Sidenotes:

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*. You should also consider moving to and using `mysqli_` or PDO, as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.
- Add `exit;` after header, should there be any other instructions below. Otherwise, your code may want to continue executing.
- `or die()` doesn't help you. Use `or die(mysql_error())` to get the real error, should there be any.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks man!! You have no idea how long i been looking at this ahah

Comment: @Prymz You're welcome. Those related questions are getting rarer; it's been a while since I last saw one where someone was using `$_Post`. I'm glad I was able to help, *cheers*.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your 3 occurrences of $_Post to $_POST

Comment: Something else you might be interested in knowing is that whilst variable name are case-sensitive in PHP, function names are not.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$_Post` in for `$eChargeNO`, `$eCreditNO`, and `$eTotal`, your three last columns. Change it to `$_POST`.